# Design of Data Access Layer with multiple databases

Tags: c#, sql-server, design-patterns, architecture

I have read many posts concerning the issue of having several databases and how to design a DAL efficiently in this case. In many cases, the forum suggests to apply the repository pattern, which works fine in most cases.

However, I find myself in a different situation. I have 3 different databases: Oracle, OLE DB and SQLServer. Currently, there exists a unique DAL with many different classes sending SQL queries down to a layer below to be executed in the corresponding database. They way the system works is that two of the databases are only used to read information from them, and the other one is used to either store this same information or read it later on. I have to propose a better design to the current implementation, but it seems as if a common interface for all three databases is not plausible from an architectural point of view.

Is there any design pattern that solves this situation? Should I have three different DALs? Or perhaps it is possible (and advisable) to apply the repository pattern to this problem?

Comment: Interesting question.  By changing the current design, what problem are you trying to solve (removing repetitive code, making maintenance easier, simplifying future development, etc.)?

Comment: There's repetitive code everywhere and the system might be expanding soon, and so I would like to come up with a generic solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers to your question will probably be very subjective. These are some thoughts.

You could apply command-query separation. The query side integrates directly with your data layer, bypassing any business or domain layer, and the returning entities are optimized for read and project from your databases. This layer could also be responsible to merge results from different database calls.

The command side consists of command handlers, using domain or business entities, which are mapped from your R/W database.

By doing this, the interface that you expose will be more clear and business oriented.

I'm not sure that completely abstracting out the data access layer with custom units of work and repositories is really needed: do the advantages outweigh the disadvantages? They rarely do, because you will you ever change a database technology? And if you do, this probably means a rewrite anyway. Also, if you use entity framework code first, you already have unit of work and an abstraction on top of your database; and the flexibility of using LINQ.

Bottom line - try not to over-engineer/over-abstract things; or make things super-generic.

Answer (score 0):

Your core/business code should never be dependent on any contract/interface/class that is placed in the DAL layer of the application.

Accessing data is something the business/core layer of your application needs to be able to do, and this it should be able to do without any dependency of SQL statements and without having any knowledge of the underlying data access technology.

I think you need to remove any "sql" statements from the core part of the application. SQL is vendor dependent and any dependency to a specific database engine needs to be clean out of you core, and moved to the DAL where it belongs. Then you need to create interfaces that resides outside of the DAL(s) which you then create implementation classes for in one or many DAL modules/classes. Your DAL can be dependent of your core, but not the other way around.

I don't see why the repository layer can't be used in this case. When I have a database which I can only read from, I usually let the name of the repository interface indicate this, like ICompanyRepositoryRead.